# What does a dot as a cell label mean?

Tags: notebooks

This is probably a very basic question but I couldn't find any answer neither in the documentation nor on the Internet.

I am doing a computation that apparently needs time (too much?), but rather than aborting the computation and giving me an error, Mathematica simply stops the computation without telling me what happened and transformed all my cell labels numbers into dots (as shown in the picture).

[image]

What does that mean?

Here is the totality of the notebook:

```
lplus[x_, y_, d_] := d^2 + 4*d*y + 4(x^2+y^2)
lminus[x_, y_, d_] := d^2 - 4*d*y + 4(x^2+y^2)
lhplus[x_, y_, d_, h_] := d^2 + 4*d*y + 4(h^2+x^2+y^2)
lhminus[x_, y_, d_, h_] := d^2 - 4*d*y + 4(h^2+x^2+y^2)

cplus[x_,y_,d_]:=If[x==0,(lplus[x,y,d]*Log[lplus[x,y,d]]-4*y*(d+y))/16+x*(2*y*ArcCos[2*x/Sqrt[4*x^2+(2*y+d)^2]]+d*(Pi/2)-x*Log[lplus[x,y,d]])/2,(lplus[x,y,d]*Log[lplus[x,y,d]]-4*y*(d+y))/16+x*(2*y*ArcCos[2*x/Sqrt[4*x^2+(2*y+d)^2]]+d*ArcTan[(d+2*y)/(2*x)]-x*Log[lplus[x,y,d]])/2]
cminus[x_,y_,d_]:=If[x==0,If[y==-d/2,-d*d/16,-(lminus[x,y,d]*Log[lminus[x,y,d]]+4*y*(d-y))/16-x*((Pi/2)-x*Log[lminus[x,y,d]])/2+x*y*Sign[d-2*y]*ArcCos[2*x/Sqrt[4*x^2+(2*y-d)^2]]],-(lminus[x,y,d]*Log[lminus[x,y,d]]+4*y*(d-y))/16-x*(ArcTan[(d-2*y)/(2*x)]-x*Log[lminus[x,y,d]])/2+x*y*Sign[d-2*y]*ArcCos[2*x/Sqrt[4*x^2+(2*y-d)^2]]]
tplus[x_,y_,d_,h_]:=(-lhplus[x,y,d,h]*Log[lhplus[x,y,d,h]]+4*y*(d+y))/16+((h^2+x^2)*Log[lhplus[x,y,d,h]])/2-((d+2*y)*Sqrt[h^2+x^2]*ArcTan[(d+2*y)/(2*Sqrt[h^2+x^2])])/2
tminus[x_,y_,d_,h_]:=(lhminus[x,y,d,h]*Log[lhminus[x,y,d,h]]+4*y*(d-y))/16-((h^2+x^2)Log[lhminus[x,y,d,h]])/2+((d-2*y)*Sqrt[h^2+x^2]*ArcTan[(d-2*y)/(2*Sqrt[h^2+x^2])])/2

totalDefiniteIntegral[x_,y_,d_,h_]:=(cplus[x,y,d]+cminus[x,y,d]+tplus[x,y,d,h]+tminus[x,y,d,h])/(2*Pi)

totalDefiniteIntegralDiff[xa_,xb_,ya_,yb_,d_,h_]:=(totalDefiniteIntegral[xb,yb,d,h]-totalDefiniteIntegral[xb,ya,d,h]-totalDefiniteIntegral[xa,yb,d,h]+totalDefiniteIntegral[xa,ya,d,h])

totalDefiniteIntegralDiffTotal[xa_,xb_,ya_,yb_,d_,h_]:=(If[ya>0,totalDefiniteIntegralDiff[xa,xb,ya,yb,d,h]+totalDefiniteIntegralDiff[4-xb,4-xa,ya,yb,d,h],totalDefiniteIntegralDiff[xa,xb,-yb,-ya,d,h]+totalDefiniteIntegralDiff[4-xb,4-xa,-yb,-ya,d,h]])/(4*4/(74*74))

output = Table[totalDefiniteIntegralDiffTotal[i, i+4/74,j,j+4/74,1,1], {i, 0, 4-4/74, 4/74}, {j, -2, 2-4/74, 4/74}]
```

This is the last line that is giving me this problem.

Comment: Kernel crash, most likely.  Do all variables turn blue as well?

Comment: Your whole input is as `SetDelayed` by using `:=` on all your equations. There is nothing to "immediatly" compute in your input. Giving a working example of your code would make helping much easier.

Comment: @Syed absolutely. But this appears to be correlated to the size of my Table.

Comment: Your given code evaluates on my machine, but Mathematica crashes upon showing all output. You could try two things: For one, try using `ParallelTable` instead of `Table`. Second, check if [shortening the long output](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ShortenLongOutputs.html) might help.

Comment: Another comment: If you want your output to give numerical values, you should apply `N` to your expression in `Table`. Also computes much faster.

Comment: With v13.0 on a Mac, `output` evaluates successfully; however, it has a `LeafCount` of `7923623`. Do you really need exact values for the `Table`? Would `output = Table[totalDefiniteIntegralDiffTotal[i, i+4/74, j, j+4/74, 1, 1.0\`15], {i, 0, 4-4/74, 4/74}, {j, -2, 2-4/74, 4/74}];` work for you? This results in `output` having an overall `Precision` of `8.4`